# Failed: this.translate.get is not a function (unit testing)

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have a unit test in angular and I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: this.translate.get is not a function
    at TranslatePipe.updateValue (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ngx-translate-core.js:1126:1)
    at TranslatePipe.transform (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ngx-translate-core.js:1167:1)
    at ɵɵpipeBind1 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:22464:1)
    at LoginPageComponent_Template (ng:///LoginPageComponent.js:228:33)
```

How do I resolve this? I already added the `TranslateModule.forRoot()` on my imports but it did not work. Here's what my test looks like:

```
const mockTranslateService = jasmine.createSpyObj('TranslateService', ['use']);

beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginModalComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        UpgradeModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: TranslateService, useValue: mockTranslateService },
        /*Other services here...*/
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
```

I don't use the `get` method at all, but I do use the `use` method and in my html I use the translate pipe.

```
<span class="close-button">{{ 'COMMON.CLOSE' | translate }}</span>
```

Here's my component:

```
constructor(
    private myService: MyService,
    private translateService: TranslateService
  ) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    const subscription = 
      this.myService.fetchLanguage().subscribe((info) => {
      this.translateService.use(info.language.toLowerCase());
    });

    this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see the stack trace, you will know that the `TranslatePipe` uses the method get under the hood. I see that you are mocking the `TranslateService`

```
{ provide: TranslateService, useValue: mockTranslateService },
```

but you are not adding the get method while creating the mock. Please try adding the `get` method in the list of mocked functions:

```
const mockTranslateService = jasmine.createSpyObj('TranslateService', ['use', 'get']);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried what you said, and it just gave me another error:
`Failed: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')`

Comment: @zenzen test doubles in general need to match the interface of the thing they're replacing. In this case: the real get method returns an observable.

Comment: @zenzen - I'm not exactly sure, but why do you need a mocked version of the TranslateService? Can you try not mocking the TranslateService? Otherwise, please share a reproducible example of your problem, it's hard to keep track of the problem in comments.